# Cognos Text box Prompt: Oracle Invalid number error

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, cognos-11

I have a text box prompt where user can enter a amount from 0 to 100,000. I have the below code in SQLbut it is throwing Oracle invalid number error.
Amount = #prompt('p_amnt','string')#

Comment: Have you tried this expression? `#prompt('p_amnt', 'integer')#`
Are you using native Oracle SQL inside Report Studio?

Comment: Usually error messages have text accompanying them.  What is the error message which you see?  

The most obvious scenario to control for is data type.  

What is the data type of the column being filtered?  The prompt macro is specifying that it is a string.  

If it is, then you will have a problem later on as the equals operator is only valid for a string where the value has been wrapped in quotes.  That's why there's the sq (single quote) and dq (double quote) parameter elements.

Comment: @Tripanosomagambiense - yes this option worked. All I have to do is go to properties and change allow only numbers to yes. It worked out. Thanks for commenting.